# Let $X$ be symmetric positive definite matrix Then Jacobian Determinant of Matrx Logarithm

Tags: matrices, logarithms, determinant, change-of-variable, jacobian

Let  $X$ be $k \times k$ symmetric positive definite matrix and $\lambda_1,\dots, \lambda_k$ are its eigen values, then consider the transformation $Y = \text{Logm} X$ where $\text{Logm}$ is matrix logarithm.

$$J = \det \frac{dY}{dX} $$

I was reading that at one place

$$J = \left[\prod_{i=1}^{k} \frac{1}{\lambda_i} \right] \prod_{i<j} \left[ \frac{\log \lambda_i - \log \lambda_j}{\lambda_i-\lambda_j} \right] $$

and at another place it is written that

$$J = \left[\prod_{i=1}^{k} \frac{1}{\lambda_i} \right] \prod_{i<j} \left[ \frac{\log \lambda_i - \log \lambda_j}{\lambda_i-\lambda_j} \right]^2 $$

can someone correct proof and point to exact resource that explains this ?

Comment: (1) It would probably help if you pointed to the "one place" and "another place" you were reading. (2) Without thinking about the details at all, what seems likeliest to me is that $\prod_{i<j} \left[ \frac{\log \lambda_i - \log \lambda_j}{\lambda_i-\lambda_j} \right]^2$ is correct, and that your other source actually had $ \prod_{i \ne j} \left[ \frac{\log \lambda_i - \log \lambda_j}{\lambda_i-\lambda_j} \right]$, which is equivalent.

Comment: The jacobian of $dY/dX$ seems to be a tensor, in which convention do you turn it into a matrix and compute det?

Comment: @MishaLavrov http://web.mit.edu/18.325/www/handouts/handout2.pdf

Comment: What does it mean to take the $\det$ of a map on the symmetric positive definite matrices?